# Applying De Morgan's Theorem to more complex expressions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have this:
$$E = \neg(A \lor B \land \neg(C \lor B))$$

Since conjunction has priority over disjunction, we can write as:
$$\neg(A \lor (B \land \neg(C \lor B)))$$

Then if we let $E_1 = A$ and $E_2 = (B \land \neg(C \lor B))$, we can apply *De Morgan's* theorem:
$$E = \neg(E_1 \lor E_2)  = \neg E_1 \land \neg E_2.$$

Substituting for expressions above,
\begin{aligned}
E &= \neg A \land \neg (B \land \neg(C \lor B)) \\
    &= \neg A \land (\neg B \lor (C \lor B))
\end{aligned}

And here's where I get confused as I'm not sure if I should keep the brackets around an expression I just applied the *De Morgan's* theorem to.

Answer (score 1):

So, just to confirm your working, yes, *so far all good*:$$\begin{align}\lnot(A\lor B\land\lnot(C\lor B))&=\lnot(A\lor( B\land\lnot(C\lor B)))\\&=\lnot A\land\lnot (B\land\lnot(C\lor B))\\&=\lnot A\land (\lnot B\lor\lnot\lnot (C\lor B))\\&=\lnot A\land(\lnot B\lor(C\lor B))\end{align}$$

Changing that to $\lnot A\land(\lnot B\lor C\lor B)$ is acceptable because a series of disjunctions are commutable.  Do not remove the remaining brackets, because it would violate the intended priority of operations.

**Now** You can (and *maybe should*) go further by using *commutivity* to associte $B$ with its negation, and....$$\begin{align}\phantom{\lnot(A\lor B\land\lnot(C\lor B))}&=\lnot A\land (\lnot B\lor B\lor C)\\&=\lnot A\land((\lnot B\lor B)\lor C)\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I assume that because $\neg B \lor B = T$, I'll be able to write the final result as $\neg A \land (T \lor C) = \neg A \land T = \neg A$ ? If this is true, it kind of confuses me when I check it with truth tables - for the original case, there are 8 possible outcomes and for $\neg A$ I only have two.

Comment: @nocomment  Recheck your [truth table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7BC+or+B%2Cnot%28C+or+B%29%2CB+and+not%28C+or+B%29%2CA+or+%28B+and+not%28C+or+B%29%29%2Cnot%28A+or+%28B+and+not%28C+or+B%29%29%29%7D)